# Save Object property like an array element in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I am trying to make a function that based on the type of the action that call it `(create/update)`, it should transform the input and return the same input with a diferent data type, Example: `create : Array` and `update : Object`

As you can see in the code, the action for both is almost the same, except for the index in the `default case` and the way the variable is created and saved.

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'create':
        $obj = [];
        foreach($request->input('slug') as $key => $value) {
            if(empty($value) || is_null($value)) {
                $obj[$key] = $uniqueId.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($titles[$key]));
            }else {
                $obj[$key] = $uniqueId.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($value));
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        $obj    = new \StdClass;
        foreach($request->input('slug') as $key => $value) {
            if(empty($value) || is_null($value)) {
                $obj->{$key} = $uniqueId.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($titles[($key+2)]));
            }else {
                $obj->{$key} = $uniqueId.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($value));
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

What i need is to simplyfy this code to just 1 loop saving both cases in a more efficient way like

```
if($type == 'create') {
    $obj    = [];
    $index  = 0;
} else {
    $obj = new \StdClass;
    $index = 2;
}
foreach($request->input('slug') as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value) || is_null($value)) {
        //this is possible in javascript, it is possible in php?
        $obj[$key] = $client->subdomain.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($titles[($key+$index)]));
            }else {

                $obj[$key] = $client->subdomain.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class, then it won't matter. Though you should look into why it matters and refactor that out and pick either array or object.

Comment: because did'nt knew that it existed